# Pandas week property result not as expected

Tags: python, pandas

If I create a date time index like this

```
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2000-12-31', '2001-01-02', '2001-01-03', '2001-01-04', '2001-01-05', '2001-12-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', freq=None)
```

and then look at the week number property of the dates

```
idx.week
```

I get the result

```
Int64Index([52, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype='int64', name='date')
```

But this seems strange, I would expect the date '2001-12-31' to be mapped to week number 52, but it's mapped to 1. Am I missing something here, or is this a bug? I'm using pandas version 0.20.1

Comment: Check this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates

Comment: It is week 1 of year 2002.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know this. Will need to modify my code accordingly